# How to redirect all traffic except SSH to one local port with iptables

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables

**Host OS:** Ubuntu 16.06 LTS
I have my server listening on port 1233. I have to redirect my all TCP and UDP traffic to port 1233 except the SSH port. I successfully redirected my all ports to 1233 with the following IPTable rules.

```
*filter 
:INPUT ACCEPT [89:12442] 
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [114:10536] 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT 
*nat 
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:64] 
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:261] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8:524] 
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [8:524] 
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1233 
-A PREROUTING -p udp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1233 
COMMIT
```

I have also added a rule for the SSH port, but I could not successfully establish an SSH connection with my server because `PREROUTING` chains will execute first. After searching, I found a lot of questions that look related to this, but not a single one covered this scenario.

You might be wondering about the use case of this type of implementation. It's a honeypot server and our idea is to set up the honeypot to listen for all traffic except SSH. I know I could define a range of ports or use the multiport facility of iptables, but I have to redirect my all ports except 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My SSH was server listen at port 22. I got success with the following IPTables rules.

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1:21 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 23:65389 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5000 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -j REDIRECT --to-port 5000
service iptables-persistent save 
service iptables-persistent reload`